# What does this bash mean: USER=${1:-`id -un`}

Tags: bash

I can not understand this line in one of old scripts in my project :

```
USER=${1:-`id -un`}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's a `bash` parameter expansion pattern.

The given statement indicates:

- If the value of `$1` (the first positional parameter (argument)) is unset or null then the output of the command `id -un` will be set as variable `USER`
- If the parameter `$1` is set and not null then the expansion of `$1` will be set as parameter `USER`.

Also the variable `USER` should be set session wide upon login, unless you have a very good reason you should not modify it directly. You can use a different variable name in your script as a solution then.

Check the `Parameter Expansion` section of `man bash` to get more idea.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the manual page for `id` (`man id`), the command `id -un` will return the actual name of the user.

The format `:-` uses what's on the right only if what's on the left isn't set.  More can be learned about this syntax [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

Therefore, the code you provided is essentially saying default to user, but override the `$USER` variable to the value of `$1` if it is provided.

Answer (score 1):

Parse it this way:

1. The `${}` tells you it is a [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)
2. The `:-` is use a [default value](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#use_a_default_value) of the Right Hand of the `:-` if the Left Hand is unset
3. The backticks around the RH runs that command

Example:

```
$ sv="set v"
$ echo ${sv:-`whoami`}
set v
$ echo ${not_set:-`whoami`}
dawg
```

There are other forms, including:

1. `${parameter:?word}` display an error if the parameter is unset,

   `$ echo ${not_set:?'is not set to anything'}`
     `-bash: not_set: is not set to anything`
2. `${parameter:+word}` substitute value of `word` only if `parameter` is set

   `$ echo ${sv:+'substitute for sv'}` 
    `substitute for sv`
3. `${parameter:=word}` assign `parameter` the value of `word` if `parameter` is unset

   `$ echo ${not_set:='now it IS set'}`
   `now it IS set`
   `$ echo "$not_set"`
   `now it IS set`

Answer (score 1):

That line is setting the value of a variable called `USER`:

```
USER=....
```

The right side of the equal has several levels.

- A "parameter expansion", the `${ }`.
- The parameter being expanded is `$1`. That's why it is `${1 ... }`.
- The value of `$1` is being tested if it is `NUL` or unset, the `${1:- }`.
- If there is a value of $1 (other than nul), that value is substituted.
- If `$1` is `NUL` or unset, substitute the value at the rigth of the `-`.
- The value between the `-` and the `}` is a "command substitution".
- The "command execution" executes a command and replace its output.
- The command is `id -un`. You can understand what it does with `man id`.
- The command `id -un` prints a name. The current user if user is omitted.

The same command could be executed by `$(id -un)`.

That would change the line to this:

```
$ USER=${1:-$(id -un)}
```

Which will set USER to the name given as positional parameter `1` or the name of the current user executing the line.

To try it, you can make a function:

```
$ tf(){ USER=${1:-$(id -un)}; echo "$USER"; }
```

If an value is given, that value is printed back:

```
$ tf bind
bind
```

If a user-name is not given, the executing user name is printed:

```
$ tf
bize
```